# how to make my program as generic using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, server

I have written a script which sends a text as an input to the server and get the response from the server as an .pcm file. I specified directly in my program about the server details. If I want to my script to be generic, so that it can accept more than one server details. can someone give me some ideas how to go about it ?
one example of server details is as shown below.

```
host = "abc.com"
port = 112
uri = "/nmtser/"
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'so that it can accept more than one server details'? What do you want to do?

Comment: yes. it should accept more than one server details.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is solved by using a **configuration file**.

There are many many implementations for this task, but the most "out-of-the-box" solution could probably be implemented with the [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module. However there are also third party solutions like Tornados [`OptionParser`](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html)